# Как добавить в List (язык С) массив знаков (слово )типа char*?

Tags: c, list

Задача состоит в том, что нужно создать List (язык C), не может быть массив char, так как такой массив должен содержать INT_MAX слов, каждое слово из INT_MAX знаков (char).

Я создала List:

```
typedef struct ListElement {
char* data;
struct ListElement * next;
} ListElement_type;

ListElement_type *head;
head = (ListElement_type *)malloc(sizeof(ListElement_type));
head=NULL;
```

И пытаюсь добавить елемент char *slowo1 :

```
wierz1->data = slowo1;
```

Но ничего не выходит.
Буду благодарна за помощь.

Исправлено :

```
char* tablica; //массив букв 
char* slowo1 
tablica = malloc(INTmaxsizeof(char));
while(scanf("%c",&znak)!=EOF) { 
tablica[i] = znak; //заполняю массив букв буквами 
i++;
} 
slowo1 = tablica; получаю слово
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: во первых, удалите команду `head=NULL;` - она стирает адрес для только-что выделенного участка памяти. Что такое у вас `slowo1` ? Это константы? Выделяете вы для них память?

Comment: @AlexGlebe

    char* tablica;   //массив букв
    char*slowo
    tablica = malloc(INTmax*sizeof(char));
    while(scanf("%c",&znak)!=EOF) { 
    tablica[i] = znak;  //заполняю массив букв буквами 
     i++
     }
     slowo1 = tablica; получаю слово

Comment: @AlexGlebe Исправила в главном вопросе

Comment: `char* tablica;` и `char* slowo1` - это **не** таблицы, а указатели на массив. Они указывают на одну и ту-же память. Так-как вы делаете присваивание указателей так : `slowo1 = tablica;`. Слова *ничего не выходит* это не вопрос. Что конкретно вы хотите и что получаете?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить вот такое решение, думаю оно близко к необходимому:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ListElement {
    char* word;
    struct ListElement* next;
} ListElement_t;

ListElement_t* getLast (ListElement_t* current) {
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    return current;
}

void addNewElement (ListElement_t* list, char* newWord) {
    ListElement_t* last;
    last = getLast (list);
    last->next = malloc (sizeof(ListElement_t));
    ListElement_t* newElement = last->next;
    newElement->next = NULL;
    newElement->word = malloc (strlen (newWord) + 1);
    strcpy (newElement->word, newWord);
}

void printList (ListElement_t* list) {
    while (list->next != NULL) {
        printf ("%s\n", list->word);
        list = list->next;
    }
    printf ("%s\n", list->word);
}

void freeList (ListElement_t* list) {
    while (list->next != NULL) {
        ListElement_t *nextListElement = list->next;
        free (list->word);
        free (list);
        list = nextListElement;
    }
    free (list->word);
    free (list);
}

char headWord[] = "HEAD";
char firstWord[] = "first";
char secondWord[] = "second";
char thirdWord[] = "third";

int main (void) {
    ListElement_t* head = malloc (sizeof(ListElement_t));
    head->word = malloc (strlen (headWord) + 1);
    strcpy (head->word, headWord);
    head->next = NULL;
    addNewElement (head, firstWord);
    addNewElement (head, secondWord);
    addNewElement (head, thirdWord);
    printList (head);
    freeList (head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).